# Changeable background for div

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I need changeable background, here is simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mondayguy/nehcvh8x/

```
var color1='009687', color2='191C26'

function updateGradient() {
    document.getElementById('gradient').style.background =
        "url('http://jscolor.com/gradient/x"+color1.toUpperCase()+"-378-"+color2.toUpperCase()+".png?tmp') center top repeat-x"
}
```

It just uses colorPicker and have pregenerated png's which uses as repeated background image. Problem is that when I use this trick for div with big height the quality is poor. Is it possible to do it without pregenerated png-s? Or is that some resources where I can generate it with more high resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this JS function to generate CSS for gradient

```
var makeGradientStyle = function(){
    var gradientString = '\
        /* Mozilla Firefox */ \
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, {colour1} 0%, {colour2} 100%);\
        /* Opera */ \
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, {colour1} 0%, {colour2} 100%);\
        /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ \
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, {colour1}), color-stop(1, {colour2}));\
        /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ \
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, {colour1} 0%, {colour2} 100%);\
        /* IE10+ */\
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  {colour1} 0%,{colour2} 100%);\
        /* W3C */\
        background: linear-gradient(top,  {colour1} 0%,{colour2} 100%);\
    ';

    return function(colour1, colour2){
        return gradientString.replace(/\{colour1\}/g, colour1).replace(/\{colour2\}/g, colour2)
    }
}();
```

Now apply it as follows

```
var p = document.getElementById('gradient');

p.setAttribute('style', p.getAttribute('style') + '; ' + makeGradientStyle('#ff0000', '#0000ff'));
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/D9W4v/)**

Comment: I think you can skip the browser compat mess these days: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients ;-)

Comment: Ofcourse I'll do it. The answer was given too fast, and time limits of SF don't allow me accept it. I'll do it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```
#gradient
{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #009687, #191C26);
}
```